# Win8.1 Error -1073741819 -> 0xc0000005

Tags: windows-8.1, python, cmd.exe

[image]

I've never had this problem on PC since Win95 I guess, but somehow it's happened recently while I was trying to 'make force' python framework( setup.py build_ext --inplace -f -> https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/setup.py ).

I'm using Win8.1(64-bit), 8GB RAM, Intel Core i7-4500U.

The update "KB2859537" was never installed, no errors while booting, running .EXEs, with .DLLs(at least win never showed an error) and also it's a new machine, so the Win8.1 was pre-installed there - probably no updating from Win8.0 -> 8.1

Any ideas how to fix it without reinstalling whole OS?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. AFAIK, 0xc0000005 is a BSOD error and nothing related to Python. It's a Access Violation Error. It has a wide range of reasons - from faulty RAM to overclocked GPUs. 
Do a memtest check.
Then perform a CHKDSK test.
Try to boot it last known good configuration mode. 
Get your crash dump files and try to retrieve the cause of the BSOD.
Finally, do a rootkit scan - because it's the last possibility. There's a Rustock Rootkit which does this kind of shiz on your PC. [Symantec Cleanup Steps...](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2006-070513-1305-99&tabid=2)
That's all I know. Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

Geez I was scared I would have to reinstall whole OS.. Used memtest and chkdsk - nothing. Run avast and it was only a little dumb file 'nsis.hdr' and maybe even 'AutoKMS.exe', which I really don't know how did it get there, because I have win8 preinstalled and office too.. weird.
Anyway, Thank you!